# JSON parse error: No content to map due to end-of-input

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, deserialization

A got error during POST method. With GET and DELETE method everthing working.

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: No content to map due to end-of-input; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input

```
public class ParameterDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<Parameter<T>> {

@Override
public Parameter<T> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) jsonParser.getCodec();
    ObjectNode jsonNodes = objectMapper.readTree(jsonParser);
    Class<? extends Parameter> parameterClass = null;
    Map parameterObjectMap = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNodes, Map.class);
    Object value = parameterObjectMap.get("value");
    if (value instanceof String) {
        parameterClass = StringValue.class;
    } else if (value instanceof Long || value instanceof Integer) {
        parameterClass = LongValue.class;
    } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        parameterClass = BoolValue.class;
    } else if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, parameterClass);
}
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ParameterDeserializer.class)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "parameter", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Parameter<T> {

[...]

private T value;

public abstract T getValue();

public abstract void setValue(T value);
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "string")
public class StringValue extends Parameter<String> {

@Column(name = "string_value")
private String stringValue;

@Override
public String getValue() {
    return stringValue;
}

@Override
public void setValue(String stringValue) {
    this.stringValue = stringValue;
}
}
```

Comment: And how are you invoking the endpoint? GET and DELETE is probably working OK because there's no request body with those methods.

Comment: @MuratOzkan I don't understand your question :( Could you explain it ?

Comment: I wrote junit test to deserialize function and I still got the same error